# How to change icons in a tree view ,when the status is changed in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, treeview

I want to change the icons, when the status is changed, of the elements of my tree view. How can I do that?

Comment: maybe you could use ng-class to dynamically add a css class to change the icons

Comment: Thank you.Will it be possible with $watch?

Comment: ng-class shouldn't need $watch. You can just modify the $scope variables and the view adapts.